# d3 How to rotate the slider?

Tags: d3.js

For http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/ab12887fd8882490b5ae
I am trying to rotate the slider. However, it is hard for me to rotate the path of the handle (it still moves in horizon). Anyone can help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQNMKB

To rotate the handle, you need to change the "d" attribute of the path, so that it draws a horizontal line instead of a vertical one. See here for more on paths: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_path.asp

Original:

```
handle.append("path")
   .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height / 2 + ")")
   .attr("d", "M 0 -20 V 20")
```

New:

```
handle.append("path")
   .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width / 2) - 10) + ", 0)")
   .attr("d", "M 0 -20 H 20")
```